# calling member function from null pointer

Tags: c++

```
class AA
{
public:
    void print(){std::cout<<"in class A"<<std::endl;}
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AA *a= NULL;
    a->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Above code outputs  "in class A" .
Since a is pointing to NULL, how print function can be called when object is pointing to NULL.

Comment: This has been asked many times. In fact, the first related link on the right. It's undefined behaviour. What it does or doesn't do is of no concern to anyone.

Comment: Hint : if you make your `print` method `virtual`, theeeen...

Comment: someone recently asked me and my first answer was it should compile fine but it should give run time error NULL->print();

Comment: @Alien01, I don't know how well it's explained in the dupe, but it's **probably** because you don't use the object in the function.

Comment: @Alien01 It should do _whatever_, because since the behaviour is undefined, it can do _anything_ without being wrong.